# Replace Switch with Generic code(.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement

I have to create a XML structure using my Class. I have some repetitive structure in my class instance along with other element. As below

```
<MainBody>
<Leg1>
<aa>--</aa>
<bb>--</bb>
</Leg1>
<Leg2>
<aa>--</aa>
<bb>--</bb>
</Leg2>
<Leg3>
<aa>--</aa>
<bb>--</bb>
</Leg3>
</Mainbody>
```

In order to get this structure I wrote code like

```
    foreach (var leg in LegList)
                {
                    switch (legNum)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            Mainbody.Leg1 = leg;
                            AddConditionSwith("Leg1", true);
                             break;
                        case 2:
                            Mainbody.Leg2 = leg;
                            AddConditionSwith("Leg2", true);
                             break;
                        case 3:
                            Mainbody.Leg3 = leg;
                            AddConditionSwith("Leg3",true);
                            break;
                    }                
                }
```

Is there a way to replace Switch with more generalize code. I need to have same xml structure. Can't change it.So value and name will change but logic for assignment remain same.

Comment: Other than your code not compiling, if there are only 3 legs I don't see what the problem is. Is there more than that, or is it expected you could have N number of legs?

Comment: @Ron My code is compiling. I can have N number of legs and I want more generalize code to write this instead of specifying like Leg1, Leg2...

Comment: The code can't compile as its written there, `case` statements can't fall through, its missing `break`s.

Comment: @Ron Oh got it what your were referring. Actually was not about code specifically but about implementation technique. I fixed it now. :). I also found a way for it. I created dictionary for "LegList" with key as "Leg1","Leg2"... Then here at foreach   MainBody.GetType().GetProperty("Leg" + legNum[0]).SetValue(MainBody,LegList[legIndex],null);.There may be still nicer way to write but atleast for now I removed ugly switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can at least pull the switch out of the for loop like this:

```
        Action<Leg> assigner;
        string name;


        switch (legNum)
        {
            case 1:
                assigner = leg => Mainbody.Leg1 = leg;
                name = "Leg1";
                break;
            case 2:
                assigner = leg => Mainbody.Leg2 = leg;
                name = "Leg2";
                break;
            case 3:
                assigner = leg => Mainbody.Leg3 = leg;
                name = "Leg3";
                break;
        }                

        foreach (var leg in LegList)
        {
            assigner(leg);
            AddConditionSwith(name, true);
        }
```

Ideally you'll want to change your object model so `Leg1`, `Leg2` and `Leg3` is a collection of legs instead of separate properties. You can still generate the same XML from that, it's just done a little differently.